# how to get bundler to use an older bundler gem version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, bundler

I have downloaded the older version of bundler I need but I'm not sure how to make my bundler command line commands use this older version of the gem?  How would I do this?

Background

- Need to use ruby 1.8.7 on dreamhost, so have targeted Rails v3.2 for this.
- It seems I need to use an older version of bundler with ruby 1.8.7 so I've targeted bundler version 1.0.22 for this.  I note this as if I use bundler v1.9.2 I'm getting after "bundle install" the error "Gem::InstallError: i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3."

Command line

```
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:weekends Greg$ gem list bundler
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (1.9.2, 1.0.22, 1.0.0)

Gregs-MacBook-Pro:weekends Greg$ bundler -v
Bundler version 1.9.2
```

Comment: did you try `bundle _version_ ` ? ref: http://makandracards.com/makandra/9741-run-specific-version-of-bundler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `bundle _version_ install` to install gems using a specific version.

Here's an example:

```
bundle _1.0.21_ install
```

or

```
bundle _1.0.21_ -v
# Bundler version 1.0.2
```

Reference: http://makandracards.com/makandra/9741-run-specific-version-of-bundler

Comment: When I try this I get  `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: bundler(1.0.0 not = 1.0.21) (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: thats because you dont have version `1.0.21` installed. It was just a placeholder. Use: `bundle _1.0.0_ -v`

Comment: this gives an error too actually: "/Users/Greg/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/ui.rb:46: uninitialized constant Gem::SilentUI (NameError)"

Comment: thats probably because your rubygems are not not compatible with that version of bundler. Downgrade rubygems to use bundler 1.0.0.  Here: http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/UPGRADING_rdoc.html